# Converting nested json objects to an array

Tags: arrays, json, object, nested

Suppose we have the following Json object, with further nest objects called items. Is it possible to convert these directly into a json array?

```
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items:{ 
            item_1: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'foo'
            }, 
            item_2: {
                id: 2,
                name: 'bar'
            }
            item_3: {
                id: 2,
                name: 'bar'
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: `Object.values(data.items).map(Object.values).reduce((xs, ys) => [...xs, ...ys], [])`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad `data.items` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thank you. fixed

Comment: There is no such thing like a *"json object"* or *"json array"*. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is text. It is a text representation of some data structure. There is no JSON in the code you posted. It is Javascript code, `data` is a regular Javascript object. Work with it as usual.

Comment: What is the expected outcome and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var data = {
  code: 42,
  items: {
    item_1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'foo'
    },
    item_2: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar'
    },
    item_3: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar'
    }
  }
};

const items = Object.values(data.items);
  
console.log(items);
```